# I have a problem : git pull :"fatal: Invalid value for pull.rebase: input"

Tags: git

when I use the command "git pull",
A message is popped out

"fatal: Invalid value for pull.rebase: input"

how can I handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a configuration issue

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase

Check for git config for `pull.rebase`

This should be `interactive` not `input`

Answer (score 4):

`fatal: Invalid value for pull.rebase: input`
This message mean somewhere in your git config files you have pull.rebase set to the value input, which is not a valid value for it to be set to. It's likely you want this to be set to `preserve` (now deprecated), or the newer `merges`

Try `git config --list --show-origin --show-scope`

Git typically has config:

- system level in `/etc/gitconfig`
- global level in `/home/<username>/.gitconfig`
- local level in `.git/config` of the repo you are in

Once you find the config which has the offending entry for pull.rebase, you can modify it directly in the file or with a command like:

`git config --local pull.rebase merges`

obviously with setting --local to global or system if needed